# Can GCC issue an error when a specific function is not used?

Tags: gcc, ld

I work on a large project where many functions are not used. I would like to be able to tag some of them as required, and have ld issue an error if it’s not used in the project it’s linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Raghuram

That option is to make sure unused code isn't stripped off. 
There is no option to force usage of a function.

For a static function (not exposed), so called dead-code, the function may be optimized out during linkage - which your option will prevent. 
For exposed functions, these normally aren't stripped since it could at a later point be referenced.

@victor

There is no option to force this, you need to define your own guard within other functions to make sure your 'needed' function are called upon first.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option(-ffunction-sections) in gcc to do this
Check this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-08/msg00128.html) for more info.